# Change code to use UseLocation instead of __RouterContext. I now have Invalid Hook Call

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-spring

I'm following a tutorial to use ReactRouter with React-Spring. The tutorial was dated and called to import and use useContext like so:

```
  const { location } = useContext(__RouterContext);
```

It's now switched to:

```
  const { location } = useLocation();
```

As this is the new standard.

When I try to run localhost, I get served "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:..."

Below are some of the stack frames;

resolveDispatcher
C:/Users/12892/Documents/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1476

useContext
C:/Users/12892/Documents/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1484

useLocation
C:/Users/12892/Documents/misc projects/WebDev/modules/hooks.js:29

App
C:/Users/12892/Documents/misc projects/WebDev/transition_site/src/App.js:13
renderWithHooks

C:/Users/12892/Documents/misc projects/WebDev/transition_site/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14985

mountIndeterminateComponent
C:/Users/12892/Documents/misc projects/WebDev/transition_site/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17811

Below is the code for App.js. I believe this is occurring from an error in switching my code to use useLocation over __RouterContext.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useTransition, animated } from '@react-spring/web';

import PageOne from './components/PageOne';
import PageTwo from './components/PageTwo';
import PageThree from './components/PageOne';
import PageFour from './components/PageFour';
import Nav from './components/Navbar';

const App = () => {

  const { location } = useLocation();
  const transitions = useTransition(location, location => location.pathname, {
    from: {opacity: 0, transform: "translate(100%, 0)"},
    enter: {opacity: 1, transform: "translate(0%, 0)"},
    leave: {opacity: 0, transform: "translate(-50%, 0)"}
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Nav />
      <main className='container-fluid'>
        {transitions.map(({ item, props, key }) => (
          <animated.div key={key} style={props}>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={PageOne} />
              <Route exact path="/two" component={PageTwo} />
              <Route exact path="/three" component={PageThree} />
              <Route exact path="/four" component={PageFour} />
            </Switch>
          </animated.div>
        ))}
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';


ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: Is the [BrowserRouter](https://reactrouter.com/native/api/Hooks/uselocation) provider wrapping your `App` ReactDOM Tree?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'll update my post.

Comment: It's [`let location = useLocation`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) but that still doesn't explain the error.

Comment: I installed BrowserRouter which eliminated the problem. I am now getting 'location is undefined'.

Comment: See the previous comment.

Comment: I forgot to say yes. It is wrapping it. Same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like this:

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
<App/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App.js

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useTransition, animated } from "react-spring";
import { page1, page2, page3, page4 } from "./components";

const App = () => {
  

  return (
    <>
    
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Navbah/>
      <Home />
    </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
};

const Home = () => {
  let location  = useLocation();
  const transitions = useTransition(location, (location) => location.pathname, {
    from: { opacity: 0 },
    enter: { opacity: 1 },
    leave: { opacity: 0 },
    delay: 200,
  });

  return (
    <>
    
      {transitions.map(({ item, props, key }) => (
        <animated.div key={key} style={props}>
          <Switch location={item}>
            <Route exact path="/page1" component={Page1} />
            <Route exact path="/page2" component={Page2} />
            <Route exact path="/page3" component={Page3} />
            <Route exact path="/page4" component={Page4} />
          </Switch>
        </animated.div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```